# Laravel - hasOne relation based on model attribute

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, I need to make a relation based on an attribute from the model`$this->type`, my code is as follows:

```php
class Parent extends Model {

    protected $attributes = [
        'type' => self::TYPE_A 
    ];

    public function child()
    {
        return match ($this->type) {
            self::TYPE_A => $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)->where('type', Cousin::TYPE_A),
            self::TYPE_B => $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)->where('type', Cousin::TYPE_B),
            self::TYPE_C,
            self::TYPE_D => $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)->where('type', Cousin::TYPE_C),
            self::TYPE_E,
            self::TYPE_F => $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)->where('type', Cousin::TYPE_D)
        };
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cousin::class);
    }

}
```

If I do this inside `artisan tinker`, I get the child relation correctly:

```php
$parent = Parent::first();

$parent->child;
```

However if my queues execute the code the `child` relation is returned as `null`.

If I put `logger($this)` in the first line of the relation I get an empty model when inside queues:

`[2021-09-29 23:51:59] local.DEBUG: {"type":1}`

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is not possible to use the relationship in this way.

The relationship I want uses composite keys and Eloquent doesn't support it.

They created a package to enable this to happen: https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships

But I don't want to add any more packages to my application as it is already too big.

My solution was to add one more column in the `cousins` table to know which one to use:

```php
public function child() {
    return $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)
        ->where('main', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $attributes = [
    'type'
];

public function getTypeAttribute() {
        return $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)
            ->where('main', true);
}
```

Then call it anywhere

```
$parent->type
```

Or you can do it as follow

```
public function typeMainTrue() {
        return $this->hasOne(Cousin::class)
            ->where('main', true);
}
```

Then call it anywhere

```
$parent->typeMainTrue
```